# Autenticación Firebase con GitHub

Tags: javascript, firebase

Necesito ayuda sobre *Firebase* y el método de autenticación *GitHub* por `authSignInWithPopup`. ¿Cómo lo puedo aplicar a la versión actual de Firebase?

Este es el código actual:

```js
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

var login = function() {
    rootRef.auth.signInWithPopup("github",function(error, authData){
        if (error) {
            console.log('El login fallo :(', error);
        } else {
            console.log('Autenticación exitosa!', authData);
            getData();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder levantar la autenticación con Github debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1) Registar una aplicación "OAuth" en Github. Para hacerlo debes ir a tu cuenta en Github y buscar:

`Settings/Developer Settings/ OAuth Applications`  y Registar una nueva aplicación.

Debes llenar un formulario como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes prestar atención en `Authorization Callback URL` debes colocar el que genera al activar la autenticación por Github en la consola de Firebase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) Agregar las librerias de `firebase` y `platform` a tu `html`.

```
<!-- FIREBASE -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.8/firebase.js"</script>
<!--  GOOGLE -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

3) A continuación debes crear un provider que le diga a Firebase, que usaras la autenticación con Github, creando un `provider`:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
```

Puedes elegir el ámbito de tu provider del tu método de autenticación, con esto puedes elegir la información a la que tendrás acceso. 
y seleccionando el método para iniciar sesión:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a GitHub Access Token. You can use it to access the GitHub API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
```

Con esta información ya estaría funcionando tu aplicación.

¡Exitos!

Comment: Puedes mirar más documentación sobre la autenticación en este [enlace](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/github-auth).  Y sobre los àmbitos de github en [este otro](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo así:

1. Crea una instancia del objeto del proveedor Github:

   ```
   var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
   ```
2. Para iniciar sesión con una ventana emergente, llama a signInWithPopup:

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
     .then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
      }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
      });
   ```

Más info aquí: [Autenticación mediante el uso de GitHub en las apps web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/github-auth)